# 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have just started to work with the CLI and when i tried to install the @angular/cli and run the code `ng --help`

I am getting the following error

> 'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

I have gone through all the blogs and didn't find any help after following all the procedures listed in the blogs

1. I have changed the

> user variables path : ;C:\Program Files\nodejs\ and  system variable :
>   C:\Program Files\nodejs\
>   ;%AppData%\npm;;

1. when i ran the command

   npm install -g @angular/cli

i found the following files under node_modules folder

@angular

-cli

---bin

-----ng

cli

I have tried to clean the cache using

```
npm cache clean
```

and then ran the code

```
ng --version
```

but i am getting the error as mentioned in the title

Comment: On which platform are you?

Answer (score 30):

I have searched long but didn't found the solution. You have to follow these steps:

1. Install angular/cli globally
2. Right after installation complete copy the path showing at the same time in terminal
3. Paste that path in the PATH environment variable
4. Restart the terminal this will help

AS after

`npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

this path is showing like

C:\Users\rizwan.local\share\npm

[image]

copy the path and paste it into 
Environment variable 
like

[image]

save and run `ng -v`

Enjoy

Comment: This really helped me.  Thank you Rixwan.

Comment: Thanks, in my case i used `C:\Users\[MyUser]\AppData\Roaming\npm\`(check last **'\'** character) and it's working

Comment: Thanks @IgnacioAra adding that path to my environment variables fix it for me.

Comment: thank you! I realize this is old but it helped me today!

Comment: It  MUST be inside your User Variables > path, and not in the System Variables > path

Answer (score 6):

angular-cli is older version, for new version first

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
```

to install new version

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: i am really sorry, this is the command which i used to install angular cli npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: i have updated my comment as well, i will just try all the following things said by you and get back...in my comment i have also updated the system variable, please have a check and let me know if it is right

Comment: which is your node version?

Comment: CLI require Node 6.9.0 or higher, together with NPM 3 or higher

Comment: node verison:6.x and npm version: 3.x

Comment: Try updating node, latest version is 6.11. And repeat the above process.

Comment: chcek this solution too [link](http://itechiesol.blogspot.in/2017/07/angular-cli-ng-command-is-not-working.html)

Comment: i have already updated the node, node verison: 3.10.10 npm version: 3.10.10, i have followed all the steps you have directed and still i am getting the same error

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, this issue is because of absence of correct 'ng' related environment variables on windows op.
As an alternative to another answers for fixing environment variables, You can simply **run `cmd` as admin** (if you can) and install angular-cli from there. so environment variables would be automatically fixed for you.
Note that, you should always run `cmd` as administrator or transfer (copy & paste) related Environment Variables for your user-account.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the following to get a current install and add it to my path:

> npm uninstall -g angular-cli
>
> npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
>
> npm cache clean --force
>
> npm install -g @angular/cli

Then open Windows Settings/Environment and add the following to the Path variable:

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin

Now ng works for me.

Answer (score 1):

*uninstall node.js*

delete all node_modules from your directory

*delete npm from AppData>Roaming>*

*delete npm_cache* and all newly generated node files from the c:\users[username} directory.

**install node.js**

add local path as:

new>PATH>**c:\users[username}\AppData\Roaming\npm**

*keep this before Temp path*

in cmd:
**npm -v**
**node -v**
C:\Users\693272>**npm install -g @angular/cli**

**ng -v**

(here 'ng' error should not come)

and now you can go to some other directory also and create your new project as

everything installed is set globally

C:\Users\693272>cd /

C:>d:

D:>**ng new app1 -d**

HOPE THIS HELPS!

Answer (score 1):

Simple executing below command should do the trick.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `cmd` can only run commands specified in the environment variables (in this case `npm`). This path is added when you install node in your system globally.

When you add the complete installation path, e.g. `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng` to environment variables and rerun `cmd`, it will accept `ng` as a command. Your environment variables must contain both `npm` and `ng` paths

[image: Environment Variable - Path]

Alternatively, you can also use Node.js command prompt to run ng commands.

Answer (score 0):

I think your package name is wrong.

Per the github page:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

You should use this command instead:

`npm install -g @angular/cli`

I think `angular-cli` is the older version.

Comment: please see my updated comment, i have used npm install -g @angular/cli to install the cli in my machine

Comment: try with  npm update. It will work sure

Answer (score 0):

There are two 'PATH' Environment variables, we need to set in 2nd section path variable.

After setting Environment variable %PATH%, in below section, I am able to perform ng commands.

'C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm'.

Answer (score 0):

instead of adding to "User variables", it is better to append to Path in "System variables". a new software install can easily erase the "User variables" you just added.

append to Path in "System variables" the following:
C:\Users{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 0):

The issue is simple, npm doesn't know about ng

Just run npm link @angular/cli and it should work seamlessly.

Source: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37227794/ng-command-not-found-while-creating-new-project-using-angular-cli)