# not able to create new project in angular8

Tags: node.js, angular, windows

i am getting error, `The system cannot find the path specified.` when adding test new project into node.js command prompt getting error. I am totally confused to create new project.

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 12.14.1 (x64) and npm.

C:\Users\user>npm install -g @angular/cli
C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

> @angular/cli@8.3.22 postinstall C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

+ @angular/cli@8.3.22
updated 1 package in 59.885s

C:\Users\user>ng new test
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I am using operating system `window 8.1 pro version`
In my system below variables added

```
1) User variables for user
```

`NODE_PATH`:  C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

`Path`:C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;%USERPROFILE%.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;%AppData%\npm;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;%AppData%\npm;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm

```
2) System variables
```

`Path`:%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;%USERPROFILE%.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;%AppData%\npm

Comment: Are you on a Windows machine or a Mac?

Comment: i am on windows. @tomerpacific

Comment: Have you tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190164/npm-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/51279032)? While it refers to the npm command, the same error as yours shows up.

Comment: Your link has not helped I am using window 8.1 pro version. @tomerpacific

Comment: I'm not familiar with this step in the installation process `node ./bin/postinstall/script.js` (and this path does not exist in my angular install), what purpose does it serve? Any chance that script changes any paths? Because other that line, this looks like a standard angular install and should work correctly.

Comment: `ng version` from the command line gives versioning information?

Comment: no, C:\Users\user>ng version
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.@JDunken

Comment: Well, if you have no way of adding angular to the system path then you're not going to be able to use the cli, but you shouldn't need to manually modify the system path variable. I would suggest you first uninstall the package and try installing it again, this time without running the post install `script.js` and see if it works. And if that doesn't work, see if your sysadmin can help you out to modify the path. If this is your computer, you should not have a problem adding angular to the system path variable.

Comment: I'm assuming you've closed the console that you installed from at some point and opened a new one and it's still not working? (sometimes the console needs to be restarted for new path variables to be available to it, although I've not had that problem installing angular).

Comment: since ng version also not working, I guess your environment variables hasn't configured properly. Try this solution. It may work for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329744/ng-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/46874999#46874999

Comment: try downgrading node version to ~10.

Comment: Have you tried executing ng on this path C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm just to check if ng command is identified as valid command.

Comment: Reinstall node and reinstall the angular cli. If 'ng' is not known there might have been something wrong with either installations. Also, you should be able to do `ng new` in any console ie Powershell/cmd/visualcode terminal

Comment: can you please post the results of running `echo %PATH%` in your terminal.

Comment: Add environment variables and check

Comment: @mohdmazharkhan can you check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190164/npm-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified

Comment: try npm list -g  . Check if is installed in your global packages

Comment: |   |     +-- inherits@2.0.4
|   |     +-- minimatch@3.0.4
|   |     | `-- brace-expansion@1.1.11
|   |     |   +-- balanced-match@1.0.0
|   |     |   `-- concat-map@0.0.1
|   |     +-- once@1.4.0
|   |     | `-- wrappy@1.0.2 deduped
|   |     `-- path-is-absolute@1.0.1
|   `-- winston@2.1.1
|     +-- async@1.0.0
|     +-- colors@1.0.3
|     +-- cycle@1.0.3
|     +-- eyes@0.1.8
|     +-- isstream@0.1.2
|     +-- pkginfo@0.3.1
|     `-- stack-trace@0.0.10
`-- stable@0.1.8. @Carlos

Comment: if you don't see angular/cli on the list you are not going to be able to invoke ng command

Comment: try again npm list -g --depth 0      : avoid including every package’s dependencies in the tree view

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following commands:

1. `npm install -g npm@latest`
2. `npm config set script-shell bash`

After that, run the `ng new` command again.

Comment: I tried your two command after that i did: C:\Users\user>ng -v
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. @Brontosaurs

Comment: i did not use run as administrator, normally open command promt. @Quethzel

Answer (score 0):

Just want to rule out the possibility of `Path` corruption. Please try the following:

```
rem for future
setx NODE_PATH %AppData%\npm\node_modules
rem for current session
set NODE_PATH=%AppData%\npm\node_modules
setx path "%path%;%AppData%\npm"
ng -v
```

Modified version to the original answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9588052/639107

Comment: I tried all your commands :  C:\Users\user>setx NODE_PATH %AppData%\npm\node_modules

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

C:\Users\user>set NODE_PATH=%AppData%\npm\node_modules

C:\Users\user>setx path "%path%;%AppData%\npm"

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

C:\Users\user>ng -v
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. @kn_pavan

Comment: If nothing helps. I would rather suggest clean-up everything and install Node through `nvm` for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are actually creating a project called `test`.

At least until 8.0 it was impossible to create a project with the name `test`. You'd get some warning about an invalid project name. Try to create another project with another name. `cli-test` for example.

Comment: I tried other names also getting same error. @Robin Dijkhof

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works then have a fresh setup. unintsall node and all then install everything you need. make sure abouth `PATH`